# print fuction in python works only if sending numbers as arguments and not variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's hard to describe but my print function works when sending a number as an argument but sending a integer variable does not work.  I'm wondering why this happens.  Calling the "prnObj" in section B does not work but the "prnObj" in section C does work

```
# Validate user's input
def inputNumber(message):
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input(message))
            if userInput < 0 or userInput > 9:
                print('List index range [0-9] Please try again')
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print('Not an integer! Try again.')
            continue
        else:
            return userInput

# resuable print object
def prnObj(listA, listB, start, end):
    print('EmpID\tEmpName')
    for i in range(start, end):
        print('{}\t{}'.format(listA[i], listB[i]))

def main():

    # Create 2 lists
    listA = [15275, 11158, 20046, 20037, 15320,24687, 98728, 45695, 35745,10022]
    listB = ['Stevie', 'Ally', 'Bob', 'Ayesha', 'George', 'Samir', 'Mohammed'
             , 'Zack', 'Eddie', 'Kevin']

    # A) print all names
    print('\nThe list of names are:')
    print(*listB)

    # B) get index from user and print both list(index)
    index = (inputNumber('\nEnter an index #:'))
    prnObj(listA, listB, index, index)
    print('EmpID\tEmpName')
    print('{}\t{}'.format(listA[index], listB[index]))

    # C) Print names from 4th position(not index) to 9th position in list
    print('\nNames from 4th to 9th position in list:\n')
    prnObj(listA, listB, 3, 9)
```

Comment: Why do you pass the same `index` twice to `prinObj`?

Comment: I only want to print elements from both list at a single index, e.g., listA[3], listB[3] so I'm sending index twice for start and stop in the range part of the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range` function in Python works such that it starts from the start index specified and goes up to 1 less than the end index specified.

For example, for the following code...

```py
for idx in range(0, 10):
    print(idx, sep=' ')
```

...the output will be:
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, i.e., starting from the start index (0) and going up till 1 less than the end index (10 - 1 = 9).

When you're calling `prnObj` in section B (`prnObj(listA, listB, index, index)`), you're sending `index` as the start index as well as the end index for the `range` function in the `for` loop in the `prnObj`'s definition, so there are no values that `i` can take.

The issue is not with sending an integer variable.

Comment: Ok so the range function does not work if the start/end index is the same so if I want say index 0 my call to the prnObj should be ``prnObj(listA, listB, index, index+1)`` which works for me.  Thanks Shreya